# How to create child django models dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create 73 different django models, those models will be very similar, so in theory I would inherit from a base model class and just change the name of the Model/table.

*I am aware this is not the best database structure, however I believe this unconventional structure may improve other aspects of my application. The initial point is to test this hypothesis.*

How can I have django create the models, without me having to define all 73 of them?

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Model_NR_01(BaseModel):
    pass

...

class Model_NR_73(BaseModel):
    pass
```

Also, in the sample above, I believe the BaseModel would also be created. How could I prevent that, having at the end of the migration only the 73 models mentioned? (If possible, of course).

PS.: I did searched several similar questions, couldn't find an actual answer, only warnings of how bad design it is. I am aware.

Comment: "without me having to define all 73 of them"—why without defining all of them? A bit of magic in any decent text editor should make quick work of it. Remember: "[explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)".

Comment: How would having 73 identical models improve your application? You need to set `abstract = True` on your model's `Meta` class to not "create" it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Spliting in different models will allow me to include a unique constraint in one of the columns that will prevent duplicated values. If they were all in the same table I would have to query and check for duplicates everytime the table get's updated, since the datesource isn't very reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three argument form of [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) can be used to create classes dynamically. The only thing you need to pass in the attributes dictionary is `__module__` as using `type` this way to create a class will not automatically populate this attribute which is required by Django

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


for i in range(1, 74):
    model_name = f'Model_NR_{i:02}'
    globals()[model_name] = type(model_name, (BaseModel, ), {'__module__': BaseModel.__module__})
```